# trace session in Oracle (events 10046)

Tags: oracle, session, trace, alter

respective all!
My database version is Oracle 12.2.

My question is - what if I include

`alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever...'`

at the top of session but do not include "counterpart"

```
alter session set events '10046 trace name context off'
```

at the bottom of session?

Will Oracle terminate tracing automatically when the session ends? And will it terminate tracing in case of erroneous end of the session?

TIA,
Andrew.

Comment: Just to expand a bit - a small bit - on the already provided answer:  anything and everything 'set' for a session (alter session ... anything) will, _by definition_ cease to exist when the session itself ceases to exist.  It doesn't matter what causes the session to end.

Answer (score 2):

> Will Oracle terminate tracing automatically when the session ends?
> And will it terminate tracing in case of erroneous end of the session?

Yes, of course, since you enabled it for your session only.

BTW, there is special parameter `MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE` that allows you to set max trace file size limit: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE.html